# Building Sitecore connection strings in c#

Tags: c#, sitecore, connection-string

I am currently working on a Sitecore project where the same  sitecore webapplication would point to Sitecore databases based on witch IIS website name the webapplication is running under.

Let’s say the IIS webapplication is called www.company1.com, then the database names would be: www.company1.com.master, www.company1.com.web in \App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config.

I have tried to modify the connection string on **Application_Start()**, but that is not the best solution (possible but slow and ugly, first request dropped etc.).

Another approach is to use config file transformations, but that is not an options based on the number of web sites.

Is it possible to modify Sitecore.Context, somewhere in **Application_Start** – so Sitecore.Context.Database would work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is. But you would not want to change the actual name of the connection string, you would want to change the value produced by it. Changing the standard Sitecore connection string names ("master", "core" and "web") would require a lot of related changes in web.config and related config files. On top of that you would probably end up in trouble, as there are modules and code out there still - doing specific Factory.GetDatabase("master") API calls - even if they shouldn't.

I've never attempted what you're asking for here in a Sitecore solution, but I expect it should be possible to create your own ConnectionStringProvider, as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms254494(v=vs.100).aspx

The provider would need to return proper results for "master", "core" and so on - any databases you would normally have defined in your solution - and then a dynamic connection string based on the pattern you describe; considering the IIS application name or whatever  you need.

Answer (score 3):

You could setup multiple connection strings entries and then reference it in the  node in your web.config.

```
<connectionStrings> 
  <add name="core" connectionString="[connection_string]" /> 
  <add name="master" connectionString="[connection_string]" /> 
  <add name="web" connectionString="[connection_string]" /> 
  <add name="web1" connectionString="[connection_string]" /> 
  <add name="web2" connectionString="[connection_string]" /> 
</connectionStrings> 

<sites>
  <site name="website1" database="web1" hostName="www.company1.com" (...)  />
  <site name="website2" database="web2" hostName="www.company2.com" (...)  />
</sites>
```

Would that work for you?